# Python recursive binary search function

Tags: python, algorithm, search, binary, analysis

Q: basically... create a binary search algorithm that is the same (aside from the programming language) in 3 different languages for the same 8,000,000 unsuccessful searches for eight different sized arrays (128, 512, ..., 52428, (524288*4)=2097152). 
The first two languages I coded this problem in were C and C++ and got normal results: no more than 3s for the 2097152 sized array

I decided to try Python out because I've never coded it and wanted to give it a shot. I ended up getting ridiculous times for the algorithm to complete:

```
-For 128 elements I got 800s
-512 elements = 1005s
-2048 elements = 1682s
-8192 elements = 4152s (my computer went to sleep so this may be the sudden increase)
-32768 elements = 1714s
-131072 elements = 1890s
-524288 = 2074s
-2097152 = still running!!
```

(aside from the array with 8192 elements, this basically follows O(log(base2)n): on average each recursive check takes 114s.

This is my first time coding in Python so I was wondering: is my code THAT inefficient (eventhough the algorithm is extremely basic), or is Python not able to handle recursive calls as well as say C/C++/Java especially when they get extremely large? Any help/insight would be great. my Python code below:

```
import time
def binarySearch(array, key, min, max):
    mid = int(min + ((max - min) / 2))
    if min >= max:
        return False
    elif array[mid] == key:
        return True
    elif array[mid] > key:
        return binarySearch(array, key, min, mid - 1)
    elif array[mid] < key:
        return binarySearch(array, key, mid + 1, max)

i = 128
#for i in range(128, 2097152):
while i <= 2097152:
    sTime = time.time()
    myArray = [None] * (i-1)
    for k in range(0, i-1):
        myArray[k] = 13
    eTime = time.time()
    k = 0
    startTime = time.time()
    for k in range(0, 8000000):
        binarySearch(myArray, 100, 0, i-1)
    endTime = time.time()
    print("[Size = ", i, "] 8,000,000 Unsucessful Searches took ", endTime - startTime, " seconds\n")
    i = i*4
```

Comment: 3s for c/c++ is also too much for binary search for 2*10^6 sized array. It should ideally take MUCH less than half a sec.

Comment: Is this python2.x?  the `for k in range(0, 8000000)` is going to be a very expensive call -- What happens if you use `xrange` instead?

Comment: Oh...you are doing 8e6 searches as well. (I didn't see that part). Its ok then. And there is no problem with your algorithm implementation.

Comment: `mid = (min + max) / 2`, also don't keep looking up the mid value `array[mid]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of solving performance issues with Python:

- Use `C` and `Python C API` or `Cython`.
- Optimize you code using as much built in features as you can and then give the code to `PyPy`

If we take the second way (please note `//` operator instead of `int`, `list generator` for speeding up lists, and [`PEP8`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) formatting):

```
import time


def binary_search(array, key, min_, max_):
    mid = min_ + ((max_ - min_) // 2)
    if min_ >= max_:
        return False
    elif array[mid] == key:
        return True
    elif array[mid] > key:
        return binary_search(array, key, min_, mid - 1)
    elif array[mid] < key:
        return binary_search(array, key, mid + 1, max_)

i = 128
magic = 13
my_array = [magic for _ in range(i-1)]
while i <= 2097152:
    k = 0
    start_time = time.time()
    for k in range(0, 8000000):
        binary_search(my_array, 100, 0, i-1)
    end_time = time.time()
    print("[Size = ", i, "] 8,000,000 Unsucessful Searches took ", end_time - start_time, " seconds\n")

    s_time = time.time()
    my_array += [magic for _ in range(3 * i)]
    i = i*4
    e_time = time.time()
```

After all, that's what I get from `PyPy`:

```
D:\>pypy test.py
[Size =  128 ] 8,000,000 Unsucessful Searches took  0.1699998378753662  seconds
[Size =  512 ] 8,000,000 Unsucessful Searches took  0.9229998588562012  seconds
[Size =  2048 ] 8,000,000 Unsucessful Searches took  1.0799999237060547  seconds
[Size =  8192 ] 8,000,000 Unsucessful Searches took  1.2969999313354492  seconds
[Size =  32768 ] 8,000,000 Unsucessful Searches took  1.5120000839233398  seconds
[Size =  131072 ] 8,000,000 Unsucessful Searches took  1.7920000553131104  seconds
[Size =  524288 ] 8,000,000 Unsucessful Searches took  2.062000036239624  seconds
[Size =  2097152 ] 8,000,000 Unsucessful Searches took  2.236999988555908  seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that C/C++ are compiled languages and Python is an interpreted one. Python not just executes the instructions, but also reads them and translates them to executable code on the fly. Another cause of slow down is the loop construct itself. A performance ratio of 1000 isn't really strange.

Comment: I just need to explain the differences in my timings between C, C++, and Python. I should just note that Python is an interpreted one and executes the instructions, and also reads them and translates them to executable code?